# Typescript with dynamic map router got type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Using Typescript and react-router-dom. I declare an array to dynamic generate the `Route` child in `Switch`. But got the type error:

```
Conversion of type '{ routeMap: RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>[]; "": any; }' to type 'Switch' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ routeMap: RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>[]; "": any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Switch': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.
```

Here is my code:

```js
import { RouteProps, Switch, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export const routeMap: RouteProps[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/Home')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}`,
    exact: true,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/Home')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}/index`,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/Home')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}/404`,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/404')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}/floorConstruct`,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/FloorConstruct')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}/dataTracking`,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/DataTracking')),
  },
  {
    path: `${base}/pageConfig`,
    component: loadable(() => import('Views/PageConfig')),
  },
]
```

```js
export const StaticRouters = () => (
  <Switch>
    {routeMap.map((route, index) => (
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
      <Route key={index} {...route} />
    ))}
    <Redirect to={`${base}/404`} />
  </Switch>
)
```

And I found that the `StaticRouter` is `() => boolean` ???

[image: error type]

I have upload some of my code to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-typescript-demo-forked-m33jm?file=/src/routes/index.ts).

Comment: JSX code needs to be in .tsx files (which is annoying if you ask me but it is what it is)

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of your code in my visual studio and I havn't your error.

Thanks for your codesandbox.

I tried some code and I found a solution that not throw an error but I don't know where did your mistake come from.

[Here is my solution.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-typescript-demo-forked-0l7oh?file=/src/Home.tsx)

The only thing who is different is the `loadable(() => import('Views/Home'))` can don't match with the type of "component" props `React.ComponentType<any> | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | undefined`

Comment: Thanks. And I have upload some of my code in the codesandbox and update my question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And your solution is what exactly I did : -).

Comment: And the reason might be apokryfos's comment. I tried to rename routes/index.ts to routes/index.tsx, and it works.